# Add next closest date from a second table matched on id in R

Tags: r, date, join, closest

Say I have a datatable with a list of id numbers and date-times. Each id may appear more than once with a different date-time (example data in table 1)
I want to add a column to table 1 with a date from a second table matched on id number, which finds the closest date in table 2 occurring *after* the date in table 1.

Again there may be multiple dates for the same id number in table 2 so I just want to add the nearest next data.
I figure I need to write a for loop but can't work out the way to run a match for each id number then select just 1 result to display for the date column. The other condition I need to add is that if there is no date in table 2 before the next date for the same id in table 1 , it should just return NA.

What would be the best way to proceed? Thanks in advance all

```
Table1
id_code     inspection_date
1     600 2019-10-10 18:24:32
2     600 2019-10-10 23:55:13
3     600 2019-08-07 13:42:45
4     601 2019-08-16 15:45:54
5     601 2019-08-17 17:25:34
6     602 2019-08-19 12:34:31
7     603 2019-11-03 16:30:31
8     603 2019-11-03 19:01:01
```

```
Table 2
id_code2        confirm_date
1       598 2019-09-09 13:24:45
2       600 2019-10-10 19:35:37
3       600 2019-10-11 01:23:58
4       600 2019-08-07 16:30:01
5       601 2019-08-17 02:30:35
6       601 2019-08-17 22:45:46
7       601 2019-08-19 19:12:18
8       602 2019-12-01 12:12:12
9       602 2019-12-14 23:25:35
10      602 2019-12-29 03:30:31
11      603 2019-12-30 06:35:35
12      603 2019-12-31 01:02:34
13      605 2019-12-31 17:24:46
```

> `Blockquote`

Comment: `left_join` would do the trick. try `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that would work, but I'm not sure it's the fastest possible:

```
table1$confirm_date<-as.POSIXct(mapply(function(x,y) sort(table2$confirm_date[table2$id_code2==x & 
      table2$confirm_date>y])[1], table1$id_code, table1$inspection_date),
      origin="1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC")
```

This goes over your first table one by one and finds the appropriate date from table 2 that shares the same ID and has the closest (i.e., first) date that's bigger than it.

Output:

```
  id_code     inspection_date        confirm_date
1     600 2019-10-10 18:24:32 2019-10-10 19:35:37
2     600 2019-10-10 23:55:13 2019-10-11 01:23:58
3     600 2019-08-07 13:42:45 2019-08-07 16:30:01
4     601 2019-08-16 15:45:54 2019-08-17 02:30:35
5     601 2019-08-17 17:25:34 2019-08-17 22:45:46
6     602 2019-08-19 12:34:31 2019-12-01 12:12:12
7     603 2019-11-03 16:30:31 2019-12-30 06:35:35
8     603 2019-11-03 19:01:01 2019-12-30 06:35:35
```

(Your sample data didn't have a case where there was not confirm_date that's later than the inspection_date, but I made sure and it indeed returns an NA as required).

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I must admit I'm having some difficulty getting this to work properly with my data. The output is a numeric which doesn't seem to work when I convert it back into posixct. Do you think it should work with posixct or is it worth trying to manipulate read dates in a different form?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that `apply` turns everything into a matrix and messes stuff up. I'm pretty sure this should work right for posixct.

Comment: (I've updated the code, this works as far as I can tell)